# typescript const context for accessing a Set

Tags: typescript

Using const contexts, I'd like to guarantee that a type is a member of a `Set`.

Doing it for arrays is pretty elegant:

```
const values = ['apple', 'banana'] as const
type value = typeof values[number]
```

For Sets, I don't know how to write it as elegantly. The following code works, but feels clunky:

```
const valueSet = new Set(['apple', 'banana'] as const)
type value = typeof valueSet extends Set<infer U> ? U : never
```

Is there a way to arrive at the same result without using a ternary?

Comment: Also not elegant, but without ternary: `type value = Parameters<typeof valueSet.add>[number]` (not really, it is just hidden by `Parameters` utility)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `infer U` version, and I don't think there's anything better. An `Array<T>` has properties of type `T` at `number` indices, so you can use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types). A `Set<T>` doesn't have any such properties, only methods that accept/return values of type `T`, so you'll need something like `ReturnType<>` or `Parameters<>` to get them, and those use conditional types with `infer` inside them.  If you want to make a type alias to hide it, you can. Not sure how to advise.